# Is it a good idea if I make use of REST concepts, combining it with MVVM in WPF?

Tags: wpf, rest, mvvm

I like the concept of REST wherein each page is stateless. However, I haven't seen anyone using it in windows application. Way back, when I'm still using MVC and MVP patterns, one of my setbacks is handling states.

I don't know if this is a good idea, but I like to know your opinion on this. :)

Thanks.

Comment: Could you be a little clearer on what your question is?  Are you speaking about having your VMs stateless?

Comment: Yes! Exactly, is it a good idea to remove states from VM's? Instead, you'll just keep the current "REST" path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends on how you implement this.  My view models typically keep state in properties that the views can bind to.  However, I have sometimes found it useful to keep that state information in a separate object, which my view model hangs on to.  My view can still bind to it and it declutters my view model.

Answer (score 0):

I've built two large winforms apps using REST and I'm starting to experiment with WPF.  WPF should be even easier.

I use MVC on the server for my REST resources and MVC on the desktop.